# I want to write down some notes in a .bat file. What codes can be added to the notes so that they will not be treated as commands to be run?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, code

I want to write down some notes in a .bat file. 
What codes can be added to the notes so that they will not be treated as commands to be run?

Comment: you are looking for `rem` More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269338/how-to-comment-out-or-add-comment-in-a-batch-cmd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cmd.exe scripts, comments are added using `REM` (or `@REM` to forcefully disable echoing).

```
rem This is a comment.
```

While not *technically* a comment prefix, `::` can also be used the same way (it defines a "goto" label that remains unused):

```
:: This is a comment.
```

> **Caution**:
>
> When labels are used as comments within a bracketed code block or for
>   command, the command processor expects every label to be followed by
>   at least one command, so when a jump is made to the label it will have
>   something to execute.
>
> The `cmd` shell will try to execute the second line even if it is
>   formatted as a label (and **this causes an error**):
>
> ```
> (
> echo This example will fail
> :: some comment
> )
> ```
>
> When working within bracketed code blocks it is definitely safer to
>   use `rem` for all comment lines.

Source [Using Labels as Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/batch-file/3152/comments-in-batch-files/10745/using-labels-as-comments#t=201612081756262526024)

You can also use **variables as comments**.

> It is also possible to use variables as comments. This can be useful
>   to conditionally prevent commands being executed:
>
> ```
> @echo off 
> setlocal
> if /i "%~1"=="update" (set _skip=) Else (set _skip=REM)
> %_skip% copy update.dat 
> %_skip% echo Update applied 
> ...
> ```
>
> When using the above code snippet in a batch file the lines beginning
>   with `%_skip%` are only executed if the batch file is called with
>   `update` as a parameter.

Source [Using Variables as Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/batch-file/3152/comments-in-batch-files/10746/using-variables-as-comments#t=201612081803345280889)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply append to the end of the file if the last code is a `Goto :Eof` Cmd doesn't care about lines the code never reaches. With a unique marker the batch itself can determine the begin of the text and display using more.

```
@Echo off
For /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%A in (
  'findstr /N "^@@@" "%~f0"'
  ) Do Set TxtBegin=%%A
:: Echo TxtBegin=%TxtBegin%
More +%TxtBegin% "%~f0"
Pause
Goto :Eof
@@@Begin of text
Here Comes the Sun
The Beatles
Here comes the sun (doo doo doo doo)
Here comes the sun, and I say
It's all right
Little darling, it's been a long cold lonely winter
Little darling, it feels like years since it's been here
Here comes the sun
Here comes the sun, and I say
..snip..
```